# Change color of some days in DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I am using `DatePickerDialog` in my application. I would like to color (let's say to BLACK) days which are **Bank Holidays**.

Is it possible to change color of a day in a `DatePickerDialog` that meets certain condition?

So far I have found only questions related to changed color of whole `DatePickerDialog`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
<!-- this is new -->
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

<item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primDark</item>
```

```
<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
<item name="android:headerBackground">@color/prim</item>
<item name="android:calendarTextColor">@color/primDark</item>
<item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">@color/primDark</item>
<item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@color/accent</item>
<item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
<item name="android:minDate">01/01/2000</item>
```